# ds.Tables["TableName"] threw an exception "System.Data.DataTableCollection.this[string].get returned null."

Tags: winforms, dataset

I'm working on a Exporting DataGridView to CSV File and I have this problem:
When i try with table name ( ds.Tables["tableName"] ) it threw an exception `"System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
System.Data.DataTableCollection.this[string].get returned null.
"`
but it is working  with the index of table: ds.Tables[0].
In my case I have only the names of the table.

I've tried with  ds.Tables["dbo.tableName"] also ds.Tables[(row.Cells["table_name"].Value.ToString())]

this is my code:

```
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in TableNamesGrid.Rows)
                {
                    bool isSelected = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["CheckBox"].Value);
                    if (isSelected)
                    {
                        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                        SqlDataAdapter sqlData = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + row.Cells[1].Value, sqlConnection);
                        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                        sqlData.Fill(ds);
                        foreach (DataRow dataRow in ds.Tables[(row.Cells["table_name"].Value.ToString())].Rows)
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[(row.Cells["table_name"].Value.ToString())].Rows.Count; i++)
                            {
                                stringBuilder.Append(dataRow[i].ToString() + ",");
                            }
                            stringBuilder.Append("\r\n");
                        }
                        StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"D:\Projects\AlatiWF\data.csv");
                        file.WriteLine(stringBuilder.ToString());
                        file.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SqlDataAdapter is not smart enough to work out that your query is just accessing a single table, so it will always return tables named like this: "Table0", "Table1", "Table2", etc.

Table[0] works because it's accessing the table called "Table0".  You can give the tables sensible names after your call to sqlData.Fill(ds) by doing something like:

```
ds.Tables[0].TableName = "SensibleTableName";
```

Answer (score 0):

Directly fill the  Datatable and without Dataset.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sqlData.Fill(dt);
foreach (DataRow dataRow in dt.Rows)
                    {
```